Lifetime may not live long enough when Cow's generic type contains lifetime
I've simplified my code to
mod fail {
    use std::borrow::Cow;
    
    pub struct C<'a>(Cow<'a, [&'a ()]>);
    struct CWrapper<'a>(&'a C<'a>);
    
    pub fn foo(c: &C) {
        let _ = CWrapper(c);
    }
}

mod ok_std_cow {
    use std::borrow::Cow;
    
    pub struct C<'a>(Cow<'a, [()]>);
    struct CWrapper<'a>(&'a C<'a>);
    
    pub fn foo(c: &C) {
        let _ = CWrapper(c);
    }
}

mod ok_my_cow {
    enum MyCow<'a> {
        Borrowed(&'a [&'a ()]),
        Owned(Vec<&'a ()>),
    }
    pub struct C<'a>(MyCow<'a>);
    struct CWrapper<'a>(&'a C<'a>);
    
    pub fn foo(c: &C) {
        let _ = CWrapper(c);
    }
}

>> Playground
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:8:26
  |
7 |     pub fn foo(c: &C) {
  |                -  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
  |                |
  |                has type `&fail::C<'2>`
8 |         let _ = CWrapper(c);
  |                          ^ this usage requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
7 |     pub fn foo<'a>(c: &'a C<'a>) {
  |               ++++     ++  ++++

Questions:

Why does the fail::foo function emit error?
Could I fix it without introducing changes to the function signature of foo and the generic list of struct C, and without reimplementing Cow?


You have a lifetime mismatch '1 and '2 must be the same but you don't constrain them to be. Just do this: "help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter pub fn foo<'a>(c: &'a C<'a>) {" as suggested by the compiler.

@cafce25 This works, but a breaking change. foo comes from a pub trait, which I'd rather not modify. I'm also curious as to why, I'm simply adding a private field of type Cow inside the struct, which is not supposed to cause an API break, right?

The short version is because Cow is invariant over T

Note that &'a Foo<'a> is very often wrong. Since you need to change the API anyway, I would advise you to use Cow<'a, [&'b ()]> instead.
